# Build RESTful service with WCF

Tags: wcf, rest, service

I'm not new to web services or wcf but currently I'm stuck in a problem I couldn't find a solution for yet. I tried everything I've found searching stack overflow, but nothing solved the problem.

I'm trying to write a very small service using WCF that should return the result as XML, Json or CSV. For this I wrote the following code:

```
<ServiceContract()>
    Public Interface IPortalExchangeService

    <OperationContract()> _
        <WebGet(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate:="belegungskalender/xml/{anbieter}/{subD}")> _
    Function XMLData(ByVal anbieter As String, ByVal subD As String) As String

    <OperationContract()> _
        <WebGet(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="belegungskalender/json/{anbieter}/{subD}")> _
    Function JSONData(ByVal anbieter As String, ByVal subD As String) As String

    <OperationContract()> _
        <WebGet(UriTemplate:="belegungskalender/csv/{anbieter}/{subD}")> _
    Function CSVData(anbieter As String, subD As String) As System.IO.Stream

    End Interface
```

Now the class implementing the interface

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class CalendarExchangeService
Implements IPortalExchangeService

Public Sub New()
End Sub

Public Function XMLData(ByVal anbieter As String, ByVal subD As String) As String Implements IPortalExchangeService.XMLData
    Return String.Format("You entered: {0}", subD)
End Function

Public Function JSONData(ByVal anbieter As String, ByVal subD As String) As String Implements IPortalExchangeService.JSONData
    Return String.Format("You entered: {0}", subD)
End Function

Public Function CSVData(ByVal anbieter As String, ByVal subD As String) As Stream Implements IPortalExchangeService.CSVData
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream
    Dim enc As New UTF8Encoding
    Dim arrBytData() As Byte = enc.GetBytes("Hallo;" + anbieter + ";hier;sind;die;Daten;von;" + subD)
    ms.Write(arrBytData, 0, arrBytData.Length)
    ms.Position = 0
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/csv"

    Return ms
End Function

End Class
```

The web.config looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="PortalExchangeService" behaviorConfiguration="pesBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
          binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration=""
          behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"
          contract="IPortalExchangeService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="pesBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

And last not least the Client Code:

```
Dim url As String = "http://localhost:24642/PortalExchangeService.svc/belegungskalender/xml/testanbieter/subDomain"

        Dim myRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        myRequest.ContentType = "application/xml"
        myRequest.Method = "GET"

        Dim myResponse As HttpWebResponse

        myResponse = CType(myRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        Dim streamResponse As Stream = myResponse.GetResponseStream()
        Dim streamRead As StreamReader = New StreamReader(streamResponse)

        Dim readBuffer(255) As Char

        Dim count As Integer = streamRead.Read(readBuffer, 0, 256)

        Dim result As String = String.Empty
        Do While (count > 0)
            Dim resultData As String = New String(readBuffer, 0, count)
            count = streamRead.Read(readBuffer, 0, 256)
            result &= resultData
        Loop

        streamRead.Close()
        streamResponse.Close()
        myResponse.Close()
```

This all looked good to me, but running the client code I'm getting a "400 Bad Request" with no further information in the line 
"myResponse = CType(myRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)"

Testing the Service with WCF-Client Tool works fine, but calling with HTTP GET never.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thank in advance for your tips!!

Best regards,

Henner

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that when you test WCF with the WCF Test Client, you will *only* be testing SOAP endpoints.  The WCF Test Client can not be used with REST endpoints.

Comment: Yes Tim, you're right. That fact made me sure that the service is working in general. But why is calling it via HTTP GET failing? Is something missing in the web.config? I really have no more idea.